# Flutter project not building anymore

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I have a flutter project that I am working on. I decided to restart my machine (I use Ubuntu 20.04) but when I tried to run the project on the emulator, the project doesn't build.

1. I ran `flutter clean`
2. ran `flutter upgrade`
3. ran `flutter doctor` everything is fine

Also, I didn't get any message from debug console

But when did `flutter run` from the terminal, I got the below error

```
../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.3/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:801:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
                   ^
../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.3/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:558:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
                   ^
../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.3/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:571:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
                   ^
../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.3/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:605:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `pubspeck.lock`

run `flutter clean`
run `flutter upgrade`

If still you have issues upgrade your `flutter_typeahead` dependency to `3.2.4`